# How to access LAMP localhost in android device for testing?

Tags: android, linux, wordpress, localhost

I am developing a Wordpress site in Linux using LAMP environment. I want to test the look and feel of the site in a mobile device. I have an android device.

Is it possible to test my Linux localhost site in an android device using wifi or USB? If yes, how?

Using - Ubuntu 12.04 - XAMPP Linux 1.8.0 - Android 4.0

Note: Before you dismiss this question as possible duplicate, I checked the stackoverflow questions but nothing helped.

Open for editing!

Comment: Even failing to turn Ubuntu machine into hotspot. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both your device and your LAMP setup are on the same network, no problem. Just let the URL (on Android) be the IP- adress of your Site (for example `http://192.168.0.5/yourwordpresssite`)

Comment: What do you mean by same network? Well but it's kind of a wrong timing for this question. Well I am trying to convert my Linux machine into a wifi hotspot and connect to my android device. Will it be in the same network?? But like I said the timing is wrong as I am struggling to create a hotspot and can't verify anything now. :(

Comment: I can't access to my site through my ip, even in the same machine, only localhost:3000 works, but 190.21.134.167 or 190.21.134.167:3000 doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

You can also use an android emulator. The emulator has access to the loopback address via 10.0.2.2.

see: http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#emulatornetworking

Comment: I will have to get back regarding this as it looks quite a bit for me to try now. Thanks for the answer.